# Removing phrase/sentence that \r\n is located randomly (R / Python)

Tags: python, regex, r

How can I remove a phrase or sentence that `\r\n` are located over all different places?

For example, I want to remove a sentence like this:

```
If you are having trouble viewing this message or would like to share 
it on a social network, you can view the message online.
```

But there are many different variations of this sentence like:

```
If 
you are having trouble viewing this message or would like to share 
it on a social network, you can view the message online.
```

or

```
If you are having trouble 
viewing this message or would like to share 
it on a social network, you can view the message online.
```

I tried to specify every variation in regular expressions, but it is possible when the sentence or phrase is short.

For example, if I want to remove `Please contact me immediately`

I can specify `Please\r\ncontact me immediately` `Please contact\r\nme immediately` `Please contact me\r\n immediately` `Please contact me\r\nimmediately` to remove this sentence. But if I want to remove a longer sentence like as my first example, I cannot write every possible variation.

**In summary, how can I remove phrases and sentences that have same words but have \r\n in all different places?**

Comment: Depending upon the space where those sentences appear shouldn't there be a `\r` or `\n` ?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
$ import re
$ remove_text = lambda x, y: re.sub('\s?\r?\n?'.join(x.split()), "", y)

$ remove_text("Please contact me immediately", "Hello Please contact\r\nme immediately World")
> 'Hello  World'
```

You can also remove extra spaces later.

```
$ re.sub('\s+', ' ', remove_text("Please contact me immediately", "Hello Please contact\r\nme immediately World"))
> 'Hello World'
```

This method has its limitations like if your actual text is `Pleasecontact meimmediately`, it will be treated as same.

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern will find all paragraphs ( as opposed to sentences ):

`((?:[^\n\r]+[\n\r])+(?:[^\n\r]+[\n\r])(?=[\n\r]))`

Try it out @ **[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX0yX1/1)**

[image: Paragraph]

## Explanation:

Find ( [ 1 or more non-newline characters ] followed by a [ newline character ] ) on 1 or more lines

`(?:[^\n\r]+[\n\r])+`

Find an additional line which matches the above pattern

`(?:[^\n\r]+[\n\r])`

Find an additional [ newline character ]
*IE: the blank line in between two groups of text*

`(?=[\n\r])`

The 2nd & 3rd groups combined equate to the final line of the paragraph.